# How to install titlesec?

Tags: installing, titlesec, texmaker

I see all the files in titlesec here at ctan:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/

I also see a titlesec folder in my texmf-texlive tree.

Apparently what happened is that during a fresh installation of texmaker, the installation process cleared out the titlesec.sty and related files. Why it would do such a thing, I do not know.

It seems obvious to me that I should just put all the files on the ctan site into the titlesec folder.

Do I have to download all those ctan files individually or is there another way?

Comment: You better install the package using `tlmgr`. See the answers to this question: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/55473#55473.) It is easy. Check the texlive part (both command line and gui). I think you need `tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`

Comment: If you are on Linux, the locate command (perhaps called slocate) looks all over the system for a file by name.